# Is there a way to listen/check user logged in status for Apple Sign-in / Google Identity / Facebook Login?

Tags: facebook, google-identity, apple-sign-in

I'm trying to either force a user to re-log into their SSO (which seemed not supported in these three SSO services) or check if they are still "logged in" from the view of the third-party SSO and do a different flow if not.

My investigation first seemed to tell me that forcing a password re-entry in Apple Sign-in / Google Identity / Facebook Login was not supported so I moved onto the the second option.

Unfortunately all the "verifications" I came across seemed to be preventing attacks with old identity tokens (they last between 10 minutes - 1hr) and thus those don't seem intended for any kind of long-term verification, only to verify a valid login. I came across the below three roughly-related pages, but it seems that for Facebook it is only after a successful authentification anyways. For Apple it seems to not have a "logged in" status change, and then Google's listeners appear to be in their **old library** and not supported in their **new Google Identity Services for Web.**
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/processing_changes_for_sign_in_with_apple_accounts
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/listeners

Is the functionality I'm looking for (forcing a re-entry of user/email and password) **or** checking a users "connected/logged-in" status supported by these SSO services, or is the core idea of them to be a single successful authentication?

Comment: Facebook has an `auth_type=reauthenticate` parameter for their login flow, the others I don't know about.

Comment: That is true, I forgot to mention that https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/advanced/re-authentication seemed to support the first "force re-auth" method but I didn't find matchign for Google/Apple. Thanks!